# Android: Save State of color change even after the app is closed

Tags: android, listview

I want to save the state of the color of text in a `listview` when clicked on an `item`. Currently I have a `custom adapter` where I am doing all thing correct but the color remains changed only when the user is in app. and as soon as the user closes the app. color once again set to the previous one .i.e to `default` one. I have tried to save the color state in an `arraylist` using the position of `getView` but thats too not working for me. Or Should I use db for that? Any idea how to save that state of color even after the user closes the app. and at the start of getView access that state and set the color accordingly. This concept is just like what we see in `email` apps. where some mails are marked as read and some as unread with different colors and text styles. I have explained my problem and if someone want more explanation then please do tell me I will.

This is my adapter code:

```
ArrayList<ReadNotifications> saveState;

public AdatperReadNotification(Context context , ArrayList<ReadNotifications> save) {
        this.context = context;
        this.saveState = save;
    }



@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View view , ViewGroup arg2) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (view == null)
        {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_readnotificaiton, null);
        }

        ReadNotifications details = saveState.get(position);

        TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtview);


        if(saveState.get(position).isSelected)
        {
                    // if was clicked set this color on start of view
            tv.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        }

        else{
                            // Set to Default color
                tv.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0,255,255));
        }

        date.setText(details.tvText());

        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                tv.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,ReadNotif.class);
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                saveState.get(position).isSelected = true;
            }
        });


        return view;
    }
```

And this is my ReadNotifications class:

```
public class ReadNotifications implements Serializable
{

    public boolean isSelected;
    ContentValues colmnValues;  


    public ReadNotifications(ContentValues values  ) 
    {
        colmnValues = values;
    }



    public String tvText() {
        return getValue(colmnValues.get("tvText"));
    }


    private String getValue(Object obj){
        if(obj == null){
            return "";
        }
        return (String) obj;
    }


}
```

Comment: Use SharedPreference for that

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple trick for you : -

Use sharedpreferences in your app.

You can save the color hash values or any string or any object in the SharedPreferences.

If you need to save states of the items then SharedPreferences would be a very better option for you.

Thanks

Comment: To add a index in sharedpreferences : - SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
editor.putInt("your_int_key", yourIntValue);
editor.commit();
the you can get it as:

 SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
 int myIntValue = sp.getInt("your_int_key", -1);

Comment: Any idea how to save state for a specific position in shared pref? This is what I have done currently. Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit(); e.putBoolean("true", true); e.commit(); and to get back boolean state = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean("true", true); if(state) { date.setTextColor(Color.GRAY); } else{ date.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0,255,255));

Comment: lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {
        String selectedFromList =(String) (lv.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt));

      }                 
}); You will get the item id in "mylng" identifier.

Comment: this is what I have done `boolean state = mSharedPreferences.getBoolean("true", true);
  int pos = mSharedPreferences.getInt("position", -1);
  
  if(!state)
  {
   
   date.setId(pos);
   date.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
  }`